# Use Hyperlink and Image in a Email-friendly way

Tags: django, django-email

Hey almighty Stackoverflow,

i'm pretty new to Django and i'm required to write an HTML-Email Template, which includes Social-Media Icons that are also Hyperlinks. It all works fine in Preview, but when send by Email only the "Broken-Image"-icons appear.
The Images are located in the static file of the Django Module and also in the static.dist directory of the main application. A few weeks ago, it worked, but after some pause and new testing yesterday, the images are broken.

```
  {% static 'ner_mail/YouTube.png' as yt_icon %}
             {% with 'target="blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/URL"'|safe as a_attr %}
               {% blocktrans  %}
                    <a {{ a_attr }} > <img src="{{ yt_icon }}" alt="" style="alignment: left;vertical-align:middle; width: 30px; padding-right: 5px" ></a>
                    <a {{ a_attr }}>    Social Media   {% endblocktrans %}
                {% endwith %}</li>
```

Can somebody maybe help me? Thank you in advance for any help!
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The `static` template tag gives a *relative* url, hence when you send that in an email, the user's browser assumes it to be relative from the current website the user is on (`gmail.com` if suppose the user opened their email there). Hence you want to render an absolute url. To do this you can use [`request.scheme` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme) and [`request.get_host` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host):

```
<img src="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{{ yt_icon }}" ...>
```

Comment: Hello Abdul, apologies for the delayed answer. 
Unfortunately, your Solution didnt solve my problem, but maybe i'm overlooking something. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Corinari how do you render the email? Try passing the request to the context for the email template.

Comment: looks like the renderer (which i have not written) is required to use port 80 to connect to the Server for creating the mime_images. Didnt know that.
Not a Dev, absolutely no knowledge if this is normal behavior. 
Thanks for your Help!